Mapping cylinder attaches a finite number of cells.
Let $X$ and $Y$ be topological spaces, and there is a retract $X \xrightarrow{i} Y \xrightarrow{r} X$ ($r\circ i=\mathsf{id}_X$). The map $i\colon X \to Y$ is an inclusion, and $Y$ is built up from $X$ by attaching finite number of cells. My question is how to prove that the mapping cylinder $M_r$ is built up from the mapping cylinder $M_i$ by attaching finite number of cells?
Notice that the mapping cylinder could be represented by pushouts
$$\require{AMScd}
\begin{CD}
X @>{i}>> Y \\
@VVV @VVV \\
X \times [0, 1] @>>> M_i
\end{CD}
$$
(so is $M_r$). A proof by using pushouts would be really helpful for me. However, a direct proof in topology is also helpful!

The crux here is to understand how $M_i$ embeds into $M_r$ in the first place. To do this, recall that $M_i=X\times[0,1]\sqcup_{X\times\{1\}}Y$ and $M_r=Y\times[0,1]\sqcup_{Y\times\{1\}}X$, where the gluing is done along $i$ and $r$ respectively. The embedding $M_i\hookrightarrow M_r$ takes the copy of $Y$ in $M_i$ to the copy $Y\times\{0\}$ in $M_r$ and the cylinder $X\times[0,1]$ in $M_i$ to the cylinder $Y\times[0,1]$ in $M_r$ by $i$ in the first component and the reversal map $[0,1]\rightarrow[0,1],\,t\mapsto1-t$ in the second component. I suggest drawing a picture to see why this is geometrically the right thing to do.
To conclude the argument, it suffices to recall how to write down a cell decomposition of $M_r$ in terms of cell decompositions of $X$ and $Y$, observe that $M_i$ is a closed union of cells (i.e. a subcomplex) and then count the cells of $M_r-M_i$. I encourage you to do these last steps on your own.

Thank you for your answer! I can geometrically image how the gluing process happened according to your description. However, I still could not write it down in a categorical way (by pushouts).

Would you mind point it out (write the process in pushouts)? I would really appreciate!!!

I don't think there is a general nonsense argument for this.
