Cofibration induces an epimorphism of the sets of homotopy classes of maps
In a model category $\mathcal{C}$, let $X$, $Y$ and $Z$ be fibrant-cofibrant objects, and they have a relation:
$$X \xrightarrow{i} Y \xrightarrow{f} Z\quad, \quad X \xrightarrow{p} Z$$
we have homotopy $f\circ i \sim p$ and $i$ is a cofibration.
My question is is it possible to prove that there always exists a map $Y \xrightarrow{g} Z$ such that $g\circ i=p$ and $g\sim f$?
What I have thought about is:
(1)There always exists a $g$ such that $g\circ i=p$, but the homotopy can not be promised.
(2)I know that if the cofibration $i$ is also a trivial cofibration (acyclic cofibration), then it will induced an isomorphism of the sets of homotopy classes of maps $\pi(Y,Z)\simeq \pi(X,Z)$. The cofibration $i$ may not be trivial (acyclic) here. However, we don't need 'isomorphism', we just need 'epimorphism (sujective)'.

Hint: Interpret the homotopies as right homotopies (i.e. defined in terms of a path space object for $Z$) and try to construct a lifting problem that gives you the desired homotopy.

@Thorgott I have solved this according to your hint! Thank you so much!

@Thorgott Would you mind having a quick look at my another question? which is https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/5006266/mapping-cylinder-attaches-a-finite-number-of-cells. I would really appreciate for that!
